# $C_0(R^d)$ is a closed subspace of $L^\infty(R^d)$. Completing the proof...

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-transform

I saw similar quastions about sequences, but this question is about some classes of functions.

Please fill up the gaps to obtain a clean full proof of the following statement:
$C_0(R^d)$ is a closed subspace of $L^\infty(R^d)$.

This lemma is important for having proof of Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.

My attempt of proof:

1. Goal $C_0(R^d)$ is a subspace of $L^\infty(R^d)$:

1.a) Goal: $C_0(R^d)$ is a subset of $L^\infty(R^d)$.
Definition:
$C_0(X)=\overline{C_c(X)}^{\|\cdot\|_\infty}$
(Side questions: how from this definition obtain that $\|z_i\|\to\infty$ implies $\|f(z_i)\|\to 0$ for any $f\in C_0(X)$? Is it a criterion of being in $C_0(X)$? I doubt.)

The following statement may be of some use:
"Continuous functions are Lebesgue integrable".
But it is important to prove that for each $p$, $f$ is in $L^p(R^d)$, so here I am stuck.

I suspect that functions from $C_0(R^d)$ are bounded(?) and continuous(?). It may be of some use.
(It would mean that $C_0\subseteq C_b$)
...

1.b) Goal: linear combination of elements of $C_0(R^d)$ stays in $C_0(R^d)$.
Linearcombination of Cauchy sequences is a Cauchy sequence, so it stays inside. This is done.

2. Goal: $C_0(R^d)$ is closed.
   This might be proven directly since every element of sequence in $C_0(R^d)$ is represented as sequence in $C_c(X)$: therefore we can take diagonal sequence.
   Its convergence might follow from all mentioned sequences being Cauchy...?
   ...

Please fix this unfinished proof details and comments are welcome!

Comment: "Continuous functions are Lebesgue integrable" this is clearly not true. Only on bounded sets.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof of uniform limit of Continuous Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2164642/proof-of-uniform-limit-of-continuous-functions)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The space of functions that vanish at infinity is a Banach space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1315399/the-space-of-functions-that-vanish-at-infinity-is-a-banach-space)